# How do I change the section numbers in an article class document?

Tags: formatting

I'm writing a project report and currently the first section I created is labelled "0.1 Introduction". I would like to change this so it is just "1 Introduction". How can I do this? I've attached images of both the code used and the output from the code  [image: Output from the code used]

Here is the code used:

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lxfonts}
\normalfont
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,total={170mm,257mm},left=20mm,top=20mm,}


\title{Insert title here}
\author{Insert author here}
\date{Insert date here}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\Large
\textbf{Abstract}
\smallskip

\RaggedRight
\normalsize
\hfill \break
Insert abstract text here!

\bigskip
\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! In your shown code you use class report! Please do not show us code as an image, we can not copy and test it!

Comment: Thanks for the comment, how can I add the code to make it easier to test? I'm completely new to LaTex

Comment: `report` is expecting `chapter` as the top level sectioning command, and then `section` within that.  Do you want chapters in your project?  Mensch is asking that you copy and paste your code, so that we can copy, paste, and compile.

Comment: Hi, thank you! I was following a report guide and didn't realise it included chapters too. I've edited the post with the code as text rather than a picture

Comment: Note there is no need to add `\bigskip` before `\section`. Use it as a mental note, if you feel you need to add macros like `\bigskip` to your text, then you're most likely doing something wrong

Comment: Thank you! I've never used LaTeX before so I probably am doing something wrong

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you switch from the `report` to the `article` document class; this may be what you want to do anyway, given the title of your posting. Alternatively, I suggest you run the instruction

```
\counterwithout{section}{chapter}
```

in the preamble. This is the way to go if, for some reason, you decide to stick with the `report` document class.